# How to add webpart on Publising page using ECMA Script

Tags: web-part

I have tried to create webpart page using ECMA script, but did not get the right solution.
How we can create web part page using ECMA script? Below is my code:

```
<input id="createPageBtn" type="button" value="Create Page">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/Pages/aaa.aspx';

addWebPart();

function addWebPart() {

    alert('test1');

 var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);

    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);

    var webPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' + 
        '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
        ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
        ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
        '<Title>My Web Part</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
        '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
        '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
        '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
        '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
        '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
        '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
        '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
        '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
        '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
        '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
        'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
        '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
        '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" />' + 
        '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
        '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
        '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';

    var oWebPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();

    limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebPart, 'wpz', 1);

    clientContext.load(oWebPart);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert('done');
    alert('Web Part added: ' + oWebPart.get_title());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



</script>
```

Comment: code executing well ,and showing me alert('Done') but web part not visible on Publishing page.  i tryied "Left",Right,middle,main webpart zone but issue remain same(not visible). when i try to add on web part page its working. so please any one help me ,how to add webpart on Publishing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to insert web part into Rich Text Editor (RTE) of publishing page (e.g., for `Body only` page layout), in that case the solution would consist of two steps:

1. insert web part into *hidden zone template* named `wpz` since the publishing page does not contain any public zone templates
2. insert *special marker* for web part into `PublishingPageContent` field (see insertWebPartMarker function for a details). This is a **mandatory** step, marker is intended for selecting web part once the page is opened in `edit mode`, otherwise web part will **not** be visible on page

**Complete example**

How to insert web part into publishing page:

```
function addWebPart(webUrl, pageUrl,webPartXml,zoneId,zoneIndex){
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
    var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    var wpm = file.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var importedWebPart = wpm.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    var webPart = wpm.addWebPart(importedWebPart.get_webPart(), zoneId, zoneIndex);
    ctx.load(webPart);

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        deferred.resolve(file,webPart);
    },
    function(sender,args){
        deferred.reject(sender, args);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}


function insertWebPartMarker(file,webPartDef)
{
    var ctx = webPartDef.get_context();
    var marker = String.format("<div class=\"ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox\" contentEditable=\"false\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read {0}\" id=\"div_{0}\"></div><div style='display:none' id=\"vid_{0}\"></div></div>", webPartDef.get_id());
    var item = file.get_listItemAllFields();
    item.set_item("PublishingPageContent",marker); 
    item.update();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    },
    function(sender,args){
        deferred.reject(sender, args);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}


function addWebPartIntoRTE(webUrl, pageUrl,webPartXml) 
{
    var zoneId = 'wpz';
    var zoneIndex = 0;
    return addWebPart(webUrl,pageUrl,webPartXml,zoneId,zoneIndex).then(insertWebPartMarker);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var contentEditorSchemaXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' + 
        '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
        ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
        ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
        '<Title>My Web Part</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
        '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
        '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
        '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
        '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
        '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
        '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
        '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
        '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
        '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
        '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
        'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
        '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
        '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" />' + 
        '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
        '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
        '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';



addWebPartIntoRTE(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'/sites/news/Pages/News-123.aspx',contentEditorSchemaXml).then(logSuccess,logError);

function logError(sender,args){
   console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
}

function logSuccess(sender,args){
   console.log('Web Part has been added successfully.');
}
```

**Update**

How  to insert web part on the page on button click:

```
$('#createPageBtn').click(function(){
    addWebPartIntoRTE(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'/sites/news/Pages/News-123.aspx',contentEditorSchemaXml).then(logSuccess,logError);
});
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, How can i pass file and webpartDef parameter in insertWebPartMarker(file,webPartDef)

Comment: 1) `file` corresponds to File object, see: `var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);`  2)`webPartDef` corresponds to WebPartDefinition object  `var webPart = wpm.addWebPart(importedWebPart.get_webPart(), zoneId, zoneIndex);`  They are passed from addWebPart into insertWebPartMarker function

Comment: Since I've posted a **complete** example, you could insert a web part on button click (see an Update section)